# If $n$ is odd and positive such that $\frac{\phi(n)}{n} \leq \frac{1}{2}$, then $n$ has at least three prime factors

Tags: number-theory

$\phi$, in this case, is Euler's totient function. I thought proof by contradiction would be my best bet however I can only get so far. Specifically, assume $n$ has only 2 prime factors say $p$ and $q$ such that $ p > q \geq 3$. Then, $\frac{\phi(n)}{n}$ = $\frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{pq}$ = 1 - $\frac{1}{p}$ - $\frac{1}{q}$ + $\frac{1}{pq}$ I need the expression on the RHS to be strictly greater than $\frac{1}{2}$ to obtain a contradiction. I know that -$\frac{1}{p}$ - $\frac{1}{q}$ $\geq$ -$\frac{2}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{pq}$ > 0, but with this I only get the RHS $\geq$ $\frac{1}{3}$, which isn't good enough. Any alternate approach or help with this inequality would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Note:  saying $n$ has only two prime factors is not the same as saying that $n=pq$ for distinct primes $p,q$.  $45=3^2\times 5$ only has two prime factors.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have just realized, however the RHS would still be the same expression even if I raised both p and q to different postive powers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{(1-p)(1-q)}{pq}
=\left(1-\frac1p\right)\left(1-\frac1q\right)
\ge\left(1-\frac15\right)\left(1-\frac13\right)=\frac{8}{15}>\frac12$$
under your hypotheses.

Comment: (+1) That was fast!